# Rails/AJAX Stringify Data Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to POST a comment to a  using AJAX in Rails (without using `remote: true` and am having difficulty understanding why my `myJSON` variable is returning as undefined, when `data` is returning as expected.

Here's my code:

```
function submitViaAjax() {
    $("#new_comment_button").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        url = $(this.form).attr('action')

        data = {
            'comment': {
                'content': $("#comment_body").val()
            }
        };

        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: url,
            data: myJSON,
            // headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            success: function (response) {
                var $ul = $("div.comments_section ul");
                $ul.append(response)
            }
        }).done(function(response){
            debugger
            var $ul = $("div.comments_section ul");
            $ul.append(response)
        })
    })
};
```

I can run `var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data);` in the browser console just fine, so I'm not sure why it's not doing anything in my code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you need to manually encode the payload when using `jQuery.ajax`. Try just passing the object as the data key.

Comment: You also need to remember that `var` declarations are hoisted to the top of the function in javascript. You should use `var url, data;` to avoid declaring implicit globals and to avoid hoisting issues.

Comment: Thank you both, I'm getting a `400 (Bad Request)` error now. I'm not sure if I'm passing the data to my Rails controller in the correct format.

Comment: With my solution below, I'm not getting a `422 Unprocessable Entity` error.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why I wasn't getting the response I expected. It's a jQuery function, but I was using JavaScript variable declaration to define `myJSON`.

In short, I need to remove `var` from `var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data);`

EDIT:

Implementing `'use strict';` within that function renders those variables undefined, which may mean that I was originally overwriting them - causing the 400 and/or 422 error.

EDIT 2:

I was getting the 422 error because my data object had a key of `content` when my param was looking for `body`.

Comment: Uh, that just makes it an implicit global. Try using [`"use strict";`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and a linter to make you are not writing subpar js.

Comment: Interesting. In that case maybe I'm getting the 422 error because I'm overwritting variables (all of my JS is in one file)